# how i can enabled my wheel mouse for my scroll horizontal in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs

i put an horizontal scroll bar on my JSX but when i pass the mouse on the container , my component still scroll down instead to scroll the horizontal container ?

jsx :

```
   <div className="scrollMenu" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp} onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} ref={scrollRef}>
        <div>{mosaic()}</div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
.scrollMenu {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I tried to used the useRef but it doesn't work also :

```
const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [startX, setStartX] = useState(0);
  const [scrollLeft, setScrollLeft] = useState(0);

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
    setStartX(e.pageX - scrollRef.current.offsetLeft);
    setScrollLeft(scrollRef.current.scrollLeft);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!isDragging) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - scrollRef.current.offsetLeft;
    const scrollOffset = x - startX;
    scrollRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scrollOffset;
  };
```

Even with the scrollRef, the scroll doesn't work i have to use the bar but i want also the wheel to be enabled to scroll horizontally